# Silverlight 4: Running a stored procedure which returns a string

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, silverlight-4.0, c#-4.0, wcf-ria-services

I have a problem executing a stored procedure in Silverlight 4/RIA. The only value I get back is null. Am I doing my client and server side code wrong?

**Client Side :**

```
public ZipCodesDomainContext _ZipcodesDomainContext = new ZipCodesDomainContext();

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new <see cref="MainPage"/> instance.
        /// </summary>
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.loginContainer.Child = new LoginStatus();
            LoadCity();
        }
private void LoadCity()
        {
            txtCity.Text = _ZipcodesDomainContext.GetCityByZip(42071).Value;
        }
```

**Domain Service :**

```
public string GetCityByZip(int pZip)
        {
            return ObjectContext.sp_GetCityByZip(pZip).ToString();
        }
```

**Data Model (When selecting the stored proc) :**
[image]

**Stored Procedure :**

```
USE [ZIPCODES]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_GetCityByZip]    Script Date: 08/23/2010 13:48:11 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetCityByZip] 
    @ZIP int

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT City FROM ZipCodes WHERE Zip = @ZIP
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean you are getting `null` back?

Firstly, your function `GetCityByZip` returns a `string` which you are doing a `.Value` on which isn't valid.

If your getting `null` back from the stored proc:

```
return ObjectContext.sp_GetCityByZip(pZip).ToString();
```

would fail because you would be trying to do a `ToString()` on a null object.

What is `ObjectContext`?  Are you using Linq To SQL?  If so you get back result set which should have a wrapper of all the data so you would do something like:

```
ObjectContext.sp_GetCityByZip(pZip).City;
```

And then your other call would just be:

```
txtCity.Text = _ZipcodesDomainContext.GetCityByZip(42071);
```

If you clear it up a bit I might be able to figure out what the exact issue is but in it's current state your question has me confused.

Comment: -The return statement was returning null is what i meant about getting null back.
-ObjectContext is what is used in the other Domain Context functions
-I will try adding the '.City'.

Thank you for the quick reply! Sorry to you and all for the confusing question, still a newbie to RIA services and LINQ.

Comment: @Redburn I haven't used RIA so you could have it all right, I was just commenting based on what I was able to decipher from the question. :)